# Connecting Java with a localhost, problem with my code

Tags: java, mysql, localhost

to make it short, the next code

```
    import java.sql.*;

    public class Prueba{`
    public static String user="Boss";
    public static String pass="123456";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

     try {
       Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd_ds", "root", "");

        PreparedStatement pst=cn.prepareStatement(
        "select tipo_nivel, estatus from usuarios where username =' "+user
        + " '  and password ='  " + pass+ " '  ");
        
        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

        System.out.println(rs.next());

        }catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    }
```

the variable "rs.next()" should return "true"
i have already turn on XAMPP, apache and "mysql"
i have the driver connector
and of course the database

Comment: You should not concatenate values into a query string, it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements with parameters. The primary problem however is that you add whitespace before the username and password. The database stores username `'x'`, but your query asks for user name `' x '` (notice the whitespace), trailing whitespace is usually ignored, but leading whitespace is not. So the user `' x'` is not found, because it only knows of a user `'x'`. Same with the password (which BTW, is also a security issue, you should hash passwords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your MySQL server is running on port, `3306`, you must always mention the port e.g. your connection parameters should be something like

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:1234/bd_ds", "root", ""
```

where `1234` is the port number.

You should also do one of the following to see the error message:

1. Put `e.printStackTrace()` inside `catch` block.
2. Simply remove the `try-catch` and declare `throws the-relevant-exception-class` with the method signature.

To avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should use `prepareStatement` as follows:

```
cn.prepareStatement(
        "select tipo_nivel, estatus from usuarios where username =? and password =?");
cn.setString(1, user);
cn.setString(2, pass);
```

Finally, make sure to close the `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet`. In order to get it done automatically, you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).